# Change system date in windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for this topic but can't solve it. What I am trying to do is to change the system date through VBA. I have used `Date = DateSerial(2020,10,6)` but this needs a permission.
I have tried such a way

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "date 10/6/2020", , "runas", 1
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work. It seems there is something missing.
Any ideas.

Comment: Seriously, you shouldn't.

Comment: @Gustav Can you explain more why?

Comment: First, apart from some test on a local machine where the date easily could be adjusted manually, there should be no reason to do this. Second, it will confuse services that rely on _past_ and _future_.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oShell As Object, d As Date
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    d = "10/06/2020"
    oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "%comspec% /c" & "date " & d, , "runas", 0
End Sub
```